# Xamarin.Forms android check whether user clicked Deny and Don't ask again

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In my xamarin.forms app. I am using `xamarin.Essentials` to check and request permissions. I can check whether a permission is granted or not in android. The problem I am facing is when user clicks "Deny and Don't ask again" the status still shows `Denied`. How can we know whether user selected `Deny and Dont ask` so that I can show a warning message according to that. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The selection `Deny and Don't ask` will appear when you click the deny twice . So you could define a custom property to save the count that you click .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Thanks for the response. The Dont ask option  will show on second time. But the deny only option is also along with it. So how can we sure which option is user clicked?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I solved it like you suggested. Thanks

Comment: I will post it as answer with more details .Could you accept it?Which will help more people who has similar issue .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Sure Lucas

Comment: I had posted my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For check and request permission in Xamarin.Forms you could also use the plugin  [Permission.Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin) from nuget .

The option `Deny and Don't ask again` will only appear when you deny the request the second time . However , there is no such a specific status to tag it .

As a workaround , we could define a custom property to save the time that we deny .

```
int DenyCount = 0;

        private async void FabOnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync<LocationPermission>();
            if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                if (await CrossPermissions.Current.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleAsync(Permission.Location))
                {
                    //await DisplayAlert("Need location", "Gunna need that location", "OK");
                    DenyCount++;

                    if(DenyCount>=2)
                    {
                        //...
                    }

                }

                status = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionAsync<LocationPermission>();
            }

            if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                //Query permission
                DenyCount = 0;  // reset the value of DenyCount
            }
            else if (status == PermissionStatus.Restricted)
            {
                //location denied
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin.Essentials provides a method for detecting whether the user has clicked to "don't ask again". You can check if a dialog should be shown by calling `ShouldShowRationale`:

```
var canAskAgain = Xamarin.Essentials.Permissions.ShouldShowRationale<Permission_Type>();
var didCheckDontAskAgain = !canAskAgain;
```

If this is true, that means the user did not click "Deny and Don't Ask Again".

Also, note that on Android 12 (and maybe 11, not sure), if you click "Deny" mulitple times, Android assumes that you mean "Don't ask again". The user may never explicitly check that option, but it may be inferred by Android.